# How can I convert an Applets application into an Web application using JSP and Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, gwt, applet

I have a project that is built on **Applets** and that also comprises of **Corba** calls to backend (which is in C language). Now I need to remove Applets and convert it into **JSP** and **Javascript** combination. But the code seems to be complex as it also consist of backend calls. I am facing problem in figuring out what is to be converted in JSP and what in Javascript.

If I convert all the applet logic in Javascript, how will I pass the javascript data to the Java objects to pass it as input for corba calls.

I can't implement all the logic in JSP as the existing logic depends on the dynamic change of data by user.

I tried various links but couldn't find the proper solution to my problem.
I read somewhere that **Google Web Toolkit (GWT)** might help me converting Java Logic to Javascript, but couldn't figure out what exactly needs to be done for that.

Can anyone guide me how should I start and what exactly should I do to complete my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the bad news. There is no generic and magic solution that can convert your legacy (as you are describing it) into modern n-tiers web application.

I can suggest you the following steps.

1. decide what kind of client and server side technologies you are going to use and learn them to become familiar enough to start coding.
2. learn your legacy code and re-design it. Decide which parts of the code must be re-written, what you can use as-is and what you have to change and/or re-package.

To choose client side technology try to search for "client side javascript frameworks" or something like this. Popularity of GWT that you mentioned is going down now. The most modern framework these days are AngularJS.

Concerning server side technologies I personally prefer Spring but you can take a look on Guice and EJB too. You can also implement whole server side as as collection of servlets. It is up to you.

Start learning this amazing world and come back with more concrete questions. Good luck.